# Pandas melt data based on two or more binary columns

Tags: pandas, pivot, melt

I have a data frame that looks like this that includes `price` `side` and `volume` parameters from multiple exchanges.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price_ex1' : [9380.59650, 9394.85206, 9397.80000],
    'side_ex1' : ['bid', 'bid', 'ask'],
    'size_ex1' : [0.416, 0.053, 0.023],
    'price_ex2' : [9437.24045, 9487.81185, 9497.81424],
    'side_ex2' : ['bid', 'bid', 'ask'],
    'size_ex2' : [10.0, 556.0, 23.0]
})

df


       price_ex1     side_ex1      size_ex1  price_ex2   side_ex2    size_ex2
0     9380.59650          bid         0.416  9437.24045       bid        10.0
1     9394.85206          bid         0.053  9487.81185       bid       556.0
2     9397.80000          ask         0.023  9497.81424       ask        23.0
```

For each exchange (I have more than two exchanges), I want the index to be the union of all prices from all exchanges (i.e. union of `price_ex1`, `price_ex2`, etc...) ranked from highest to lowest. Then I want to create two `size` columns for each exchange based on the `side` parameter of that exchange. The output should look like this where empty columns are `NaN`.

I am not sure what is the best pandas function to do this, whether it is pivot or melt and how to use that function when I have more than 1 binary column I am flattening.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a three step process. After you correct your multiindexed columns, you should stack your dataset, then pivot it.

First, clean up the multiindex columns so that you more easily transform:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1', '2'], [col[:-4] for col in df.columns[:3]]], names=['exchange', 'params'])

exchange           1                       2            
params         price side   size       price side   size
0         9380.59650  bid  0.416  9437.24045  bid   10.0
1         9394.85206  bid  0.053  9487.81185  bid  556.0
2         9397.80000  ask  0.023  9497.81424  ask   23.0
```

Then stack and append the exchange num to the `bid` and `ask` values:

```
df = df.swaplevel(axis=1).stack()
df['side'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.side + '_ex' + row.name[1], axis=1)       

params           price     side     size
  exchange                              
0 1         9380.59650  bid_ex1    0.416
  2         9437.24045  bid_ex2   10.000
1 1         9394.85206  bid_ex1    0.053
  2         9487.81185  bid_ex2  556.000
2 1         9397.80000  ask_ex1    0.023
  2         9497.81424  ask_ex2   23.000
```

Finally, pivot and sort by price:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['price'], values=['size'], columns=['side']).sort_values('price', ascending=False) 

params        size                        
side       ask_ex1 ask_ex2 bid_ex1 bid_ex2
price                                     
9497.81424     NaN    23.0     NaN     NaN
9487.81185     NaN     NaN     NaN   556.0
9437.24045     NaN     NaN     NaN    10.0
9397.80000   0.023     NaN     NaN     NaN
9394.85206     NaN     NaN   0.053     NaN
9380.59650     NaN     NaN   0.416     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Please make a dataframe with the data that you show us and name it something 'example.csv'

```
   price_ex1     side_ex1      size_ex1  price_ex2   side_ex2    size_ex2
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

df1 = df[['price_ex1','side_ex1','size_ex1']]
df2 = df[['price_ex2','side_ex2','size_ex2']]

df3 = df1.append(df2)
df4 = df3[['price_ex1','price_ex2']]
arr = df4.values
df3['price_ex1'] = arr[~np.isnan(arr)].astype(float)
df3.drop(columns=['price_ex2'], inplace=True)
df3.columns = ['price', 'bid_ex1', 'ask_ex1', 'bid_ex2', 'ask_ex2']

def change(bid_ex1, ask_ex1, bid_ex2, ask_ex2, col_name):
    if col_name == 'bid_ex1_col':
        if (bid_ex1 != np.nan or bid_ex2 != np.nan) and bid_ex1 == 'bid':
            return bid_ex2
        else: 
            return bid_ex1

    if col_name == 'ask_ex1_col':
        if (bid_ex1 != np.nan or bid_ex2 != np.nan) and bid_ex1 == 'ask':
            return bid_ex2   
        else: 
            return ask_ex1

    if col_name == 'ask_ex2_col':
        if (ask_ex1 != np.nan or ask_ex2 != np.nan) and ask_ex1 == 'ask':
            return ask_ex2   
        else: 
            return ask_ex1

    if col_name == 'bid_ex2_col':
        if (ask_ex1 != np.nan or ask_ex2 != np.nan) and ask_ex1 == 'bid':
            return ask_ex2   
        else: 
            return ask_ex1

df3['bid_ex1_col'] = df3.apply(lambda row: change(row['bid_ex1'],row['ask_ex1'],row['bid_ex2'],row['ask_ex2'], 'bid_ex1_col'), axis=1)
df3['ask_ex1_col'] = df3.apply(lambda row: change(row['bid_ex1'],row['ask_ex1'],row['bid_ex2'],row['ask_ex2'], 'ask_ex1_col'), axis=1)

df3['ask_ex2_col'] = df3.apply(lambda row: change(row['bid_ex1'],row['ask_ex1'],row['bid_ex2'],row['ask_ex2'], 'ask_ex2_col'), axis=1)
df3['bid_ex2_col'] = df3.apply(lambda row: change(row['bid_ex1'],row['ask_ex1'],row['bid_ex2'],row['ask_ex2'], 'bid_ex2_col'), axis=1)

df3.drop(columns=['bid_ex1', 'ask_ex1', 'bid_ex2', 'ask_ex2'], inplace=True)

df3.replace(to_replace='ask', value=np.nan,inplace=True)
df3.replace(to_replace='bid', value=np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to flip to long form with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) before flipping back to wide form with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(names_to = ('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex'), 
              values_to=('price','side','size'), 
              names_pattern=['price', 'side', 'size'])
.loc[:, ['price', 'side','ex','size']]
.assign(ex = lambda df: df.ex.str.split('_').str[-1])
.pivot_wider('price', ('side', 'ex'), 'size')
.sort_values('price', ascending = False)
)

        price  bid_ex1  ask_ex1  bid_ex2  ask_ex2
5  9497.81424      NaN      NaN      NaN     23.0
4  9487.81185      NaN      NaN    556.0      NaN
3  9437.24045      NaN      NaN     10.0      NaN
2  9397.80000      NaN    0.023      NaN      NaN
1  9394.85206    0.053      NaN      NaN      NaN
0  9380.59650    0.416      NaN      NaN      NaN
```